# cassandra stop writing after some time

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I have a problem: i write entries from java code to cassandra database, it works for a while, and then stops writing. (nodetool cfstats keyspace.users -H on all nodes show no changes in Number of keys (estimate))

Configuration : 4 nodes (4GB, 4GB, 4GB, and 6GB RAM).

I am using datastax driver, and connection like

```
private Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
        .addContactPoints(<points>)
        .build();

private Session session = cluster.connect("keyspace");
private MappingManager mappingManager = new MappingManager(session);
```

...

I do insert in database like

```
public void writeUser(User user) {
    Mapper<User> mapper = mappingManager.mapper(User.class);
    mapper.saveAsync(user, Mapper.Option.timestamp(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(System.nanoTime())));
}
```

I also tried

```
public void writeUser(User user) {
    Mapper<User> mapper = mappingManager.mapper(User.class);
    mapper.save(user);
}
```

And two variants between.

In debug.log from server i see

```
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2016-05-11 12:21:14,565 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2000380153 for /node
```

Maybe the problem is, that server in another country? But why it is writing entities at the beginning? How can i fix my problem?

Another update: session.execute on mapper.save returns ResultSet[ exhausted: true, Columns[]]

Comment: And also, why number of writes in nodetool cfstats changes, but estimate number of keys - not?

Comment: Another update: session.execute in mapper.save returns ResultSet[ exhausted: true, Columns[]]